# Customizar / definir a ordem eixo X gráfico barras matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Gerei um gráfico, com valores para cada ano, de 2011 até 2015. 
mas a geração do gráfico, no eixo X, os anos estão agrupados de acordo com os valores, não estão na sequência correta (2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015). Qual comando posso usar para fixar, determinar que o eixo X seja ordenado com base na ordem dos anos e não nos valores de cada um?

O código é assim:

```
#Já que cada linha do dataframe é uma ocorrência registrada, então quais os dias que tiveram a maior ocorrência?
semana = {'Friday': 'Sexta-feira', 'Wednesday': 'Quarta-feira', 'Tuesday': 'Terça-feira', 'Thursday': 'Quinta-feira', 'Monday': 'Segunda-feira', 'Saturday': 'Sábado', 'Sunday': 'Domingo'}
dfbh['dia_da_semana'].replace(semana, inplace=True)
dfbh['dia_da_semana'].value_counts()
```

O resultado do `value_counts` é:

> Sexta-feira      16022
>   Quarta-feira     14526
>   Terça-feira      14479
>   Quinta-feira     14354
>   Segunda-feira    14255
>   Sábado           13883
>   Domingo          10620
>   Name: dia_da_semana, dtype: int64

Na sequência é plotado um gráfico com o código a seguir:

```
dfbh['dia_da_semana'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar', figsize=(10, 5), fontsize = 10, color=['b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b']);
```

E o gráfico é gerado na sequência acima. Quero alterar para a sequência normal da semana. Talvez um comando `sort_index()` ?

Comment: Sem colocar um exemplo de como você declarou as variáveis fica difícil saber. Use um [mcve] que isto irá ajudar a alguém dar uma resposta.

Comment: Grato Guto pela observação e o link para leitura do conteúdo de exemplo que deve ser seguido.

Comment: Devo dizer que sua pergunta está bem melhor, porém, o seu dados não estão declarados (você apenas mostra o resultado), assim como você não está com um header completo, sendo que é necessário um pouco de imaginacão pra obter os seu resultado. Mas assim já está melhor que antes. Recomendo uma outra edicão, agora com a [formatacão adequada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Estou a ver isso em um break e outro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas maneira de resolver isso, Como você falou, um `sort_index()` talvez resolva, mas isso depende de quão flexível é o algoritmo que faz o sorting.

Abaixo segue uma solução com o uso de um dataframe extra e um `merge`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.DataFrame({'day':['Mon', 'Tues', 'Fri','Weds', 'Sun','Thurs', 'Sat'],   
'cc':[34,65,23,66,23,51,22]})
Out[5]: 
   cc    day
0  34    Mon
1  65   Tues
2  23    Fri
3  66   Weds
4  23    Sun
5  51  Thurs
6  22    Sat


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Weds', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    'num': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df = pd.merge(df, df2, on='day')
df

Out: 
   cc    day  num
0  34    Mon    0
1  65   Tues    1
2  23    Fri    4
3  66   Weds    2
4  23    Sun    6
5  51  Thurs    3
6  22    Sat    5


df = df.sort_values('num')
df.plot(kind='bar', x='day')
```

e isto dá o gráfico abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que aqui ele plota `num` também, mas isso é fácil de resolver usando um `plot` adequado, direto do `matplotlib`.

Como nota, usei um dos métodos descritos [nesta pergunta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635110/sorting-the-order-of-bars-in-pandas-matplotlib-bar-plots). Os outros procedimentos descritos lá são interessantes também.

Comment: como vc deixou os dias da semana na vertical?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!
Muito obrigado pela ajuda. 
Como resolvi?
**usando loc[ ]
criei uma variável antes:**

```
dias_ordenados = ['Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado', 'Domingo']
```

**Depois, no código do gráfico que estava assim:**

```
dfbh['dia_da_semana'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar', figsize=(10, 5), fontsize = 10, color=['b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b']);
```

**Dividi o código e criei outra variável:**

```
dias2 = dfbh['dia da_semana'].value_counts()
```

**E aí fiz o código do gráfico com o loc[ ], assim:**

```
dias2.loc[dias_ordenados].plot(kind = 'bar', figsize=(10, 5), fontsize = 10, color=['b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b']);
```

**E o gráfico, que antes estava sendo ordenado pelos valores obtidos pelo value_counts, ficou ordenado pela variável que criei e chamei com o loc[ ].**